# Django Rest Framework Serializer POST data not receiving arrays

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the DRF test api for testing my serializers, for instance I made my data like this:

```
image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../media/', 'product_images/', 'myimage.png')
    with open(image_path) as image:
        encoded_image = base64.b64decode(image.read())
        data = {
            u'small_name': u'Product Test Case Small Name',
            u'large_name': u'Product Test Case Large Name',
            u'description': u'Product Test Case Description',
            u'images': [
                {u'image': encoded_image}
            ],
            u'variants': [
                {u'value': u'123456789'}
            ]
        }
response = self.client.post(url, data, 'multipart')
```

However when I receive the data on the respective serializer the `variants` array and the `images` array are empty.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Try `self.client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')`

Comment: Is `image` containing image file or base64 encoded string? (The above solution will not work if its a image file).

Comment: Yes, I'm encoding an image on a base64 string.

Comment: Then it should work with `json` content type. The issue is probably with the encoded image string. Please add the code by which you are encoding  the image.

Comment: Sure, I'will edit it with the image code.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Linovia and Rahul Gupta I was able to resolve the image and arrays problem. I changed my serializer to receive an Base64ImageField using the one provided by `django-extra-fields`. Rahul also pointed a silly error on my code.
I'll leave some code to help someone with the same problem.

**serializers.py file**

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64ImageField


class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    source = Base64ImageField(source='image', required=False, )
```

**test.py file**

```
image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../media/', 'product_images/', 'myimage.png')
with open(image_path) as image:
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image.read())
        data = {
                u'small_name': u'Product Test Case Small Name',
                u'large_name': u'Product Test Case Large Name',
                u'description': u'Product Test Case Description',
                u'images': [
                    {u'source': encoded_image}
                ],
                u'variants': [
                    {u'value': u'123456789'}
                ]
            }

response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to encode the image using `base64.b64encode()` instead of the `base64.b64decode()` method.

```
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image.read())
```

Also, send json encoded data with content type set to `application/json`.

```
self.client.post(url, json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I'm having a new issue using this, I got an UnicodeDecodeError, maybe because I'm sending an image together with the data?

Comment: @RodrigoAraújoValente Try using `base64.b64encode` instead of `base64.b64decode`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgeted to update to update the status, I already resolved this issue, I'm using now a Base64ImageField for my serializer and I changed what you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can not have both the image upload and nested data.
Either you want to upload the image and use multipart encoding (HTML forms) which means your arrays will not work (unless it's a list of foreign key or similar). This could work with JSon content type but then you'll loose the ability to upload image. Your option there might be to encode with base64 the image and upload it but you'll have to customize a few things on the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the [`format`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#making-requests) of `client`to `JSON`:

```
response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
```